# Blazor Server-Side - Get Base URL in Program.cs before build?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For a server-side Blazor application, is there a way to get the user's baseURI in the Program.cs page prior to build? The url is used to determine and build the applicable connection string in the DBContext. I have searched the site for a solution to this, but everyone seems to only be addressing WASM solutions.

Comment: There is no user context when you build the app in server mode.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks for the response. Does this mean that, for it to work, the app will need to be either WASM or possibly both?

Comment: How many DbContext options are there?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis In the app there are three possibilities, but only two will ever need to be added at one time.

Comment: I'm travelling so don't have access to my full Dev environment.  However, this may help you.  In Blazor Server you get the base url for the `HttpClient` like this:  `builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });`  You may be able to uses something similar.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I actually thought of that, but I get an error saying, "WebApplicationBuilder" does not contain a definition for HostEnvironment."